# django-qrcode: 'qr_tags' is not a valid tag library: Template library qr_tags not found

Tags: python, django, qr-code

I installed with

```
pip install django-qrcode
```

added 'qrcode' to 'INSTALLED_APPS' in my settings.py

when I try to load {% load qr tags %}, I get the following error:

> 'qr_tags' is not a valid tag library: Template library qr_tags not found, tried django.templatetags.qr_tags,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.qr_tags,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.qr_tags

Note: I using python 2.7 and django 1.4.22

Thanks

Comment: It looks as if `qrcode` is not actually in `INSTALLED_APPS` - if it were, then the error message would include `qrcode.templatetags.qr_tags`. Maybe you have forgotten to restart your server after changing the settings, or you have updated the wrong settings file.